# Why can I not connect to a remote desktop? [Solved]

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

I am using a VPN connection and a remote desktop client called Rammina.
The VPN is successfully connected and I am able to connect remotely to a windows server using a Remote Desktop Protocol (I put the Server = DNS server IP address). However, when I enter the IP address of a remote desktop (Windows 10), I have the following error message: Unable to connect to the RDP server

Can you please advise?

**Note: I am able to connect remotely from a Windows to Windows.

## Solution: Security had to be set to Negotiate and the user name was incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Whenever this happens to me deleting all the Remmina RDP certificates gets it back up and running.

The certificates are located at ~/.freerdp/known_hosts/

> rm -rf ~/.freerdp/known_hosts/*

It is nothing dangerous, you will just need to re-confirm connection to the remote pc with a yes/no question at next attempt. Other than this little bug I find Remmina to be an excellent remote connection tool, never had any other Remmina related problems.

Comment: I tried this method but i have the same issue.

Comment: If you connect to the DNS server and then from the DNS server to the Windows 10 machine can you establish a successful connection? Also can you ping the Windows 10 directly from your PC? And finally, are you able to get a Windows-Windows remote connection over the VPN or only when in the same LAN?

Comment: On the Remmina side of things I find only one more probable cause. Right click your connection, select Edit, in the Advanced tab select RDP for the Security option (the default is negotiate).

Comment: -RDP is selected for the Security option.
-I am able to get a Windows-Windows remote connection over the VPN (i have windows7 installed inside Linux using virtual box,  and i am able to connect to the other PC (Windows10)). Since i have access to the other PC over VPN when i use windows, i am able to ping.

Comment: Note: I have the same issue with Remote Desktop Viewer

Comment: Your networking is good for sure since you can connect from windows 7 virtual machine. Other than we already went through, some people mentioned that the color depth and quality caused issues to them. Some people just couldn't get a connection, set to True Color and then they went through. Try messing a bit with your quality settings. If this does not do it either I do not know what else it could be.

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved!. Bellow are the following issues:

1) Security had to be set to Negotiate. It is not working with RDP.

2) My user name was incorrect: i was using domain_name\my_user_name instead of simply using my_user_name

**Note: Color depth was not the problem. All of the settings are working.